# Can anyone solve this hard differential equation involving a derivative squared?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have been trying to solve this diff. equation for quite some time now but haven't been able to do it correctly. It describes the lost height of the water $h$ at a certain time $t$ of a leaking reservoir. I have obtained this equation by using Torricelli's law as well as the law of continuity. At $t=0$, the seal is removed and the reservoir starts leaking. Moreover, $A_O > A_G$ and to be less precise it can be assumed $A_O >> A_G$, however, I would like to solve it as precisely as possible. The equation is:

$$\frac{2gA_O^2}{A_O^2 - A_ G^2}h(t)+\frac{A_O^2}{A_G^2}\bigg(\frac{dh(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2 - \frac{2gA_O^2}{A_O^2 - A_G^2}H_0=0$$   with $h(0)=0$. Additionally, $h(t)$ is bounded above by $H_0$, is a strictly increasing function and thus also $\lim_{t \to \inf} h(t)=H_0$

The constants:

- $A_O$ is the surface of the top of the reservoir.
- $A_G$ is the surface area of the hole.
- $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.
- $H_0$ is the height of the water at t=0.

The simplified formula would be:
$$\lambda h(t)+\mu\left(\frac{dh(t)}{dt}\right)^2-\lambda H_0=0$$

And just to be clear $\bigg(\frac{dh(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2$ is simply the first derivative squared not the second derivative.

I really hope someone can help me solve this!
If there is anything unclear or you want more information please ask I will check this post regularly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Put the $h'(t)^2$ on one side an everything else on the other side. Then take the square root and the ODE becomes separable

Comment: One thought: You can re-arrange the last equation into
$$
\frac{\mu}{\lambda}( h' )^2 = H_0 - h \qquad
\Rightarrow \qquad \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\lambda}} h' = \sqrt{H_0 - h}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, write $h(t)=H_0+f(t)$ to get a slightly simpler equation
$$
\frac{2gA_O^2}{A_O^2 - A_ G^2}f(t)+\frac{A_O^2}{A_G^2}\bigg(\frac{df(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2=0.
$$
Writing $r=A_O/A_G$, we can simplify the constants and find
$$
\frac{2g}{r^2 - 1}f(t)+\bigg(\frac{df(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2=0.
$$
If $f'(t)=0$, the equation tells you $f(t)=0$.

I'll assume $r>1$ so that the equation forces $f\leq0$.
This holds as $A_0>A_G$.
The other case will be similar but I will stick to this choice as in the updated question.

If $f'(t)\neq0$, you get
$$
f'(t)
=
\pm\sqrt{-\frac{2g}{r^2 - 1}f(t)}
$$
or
$$
\frac{df}{-\sqrt{\frac{2g}{r^2 - 1}f}}
=
\pm dt.
$$
Integrating gives
$$
\sqrt{\frac{r^2 - 1}{8g}}
\sqrt{-f}
=
t_0\pm t
$$
for some $t_0$, so
$$
f(t)
=
-\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}
(t_0\pm t)^2.
$$
As the time difference is squared anyway, you can rewrite this general solution as
$$
f(t)
=
-\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}
(t-t_0)^2.
$$
This gives you two kinds of solutions, and for $r<1$ you will get something similar.

Be careful with solutions when $f=0$ (which is at $t=t_0$).
There the solution fails to be unique because the function can stop at the zero level.
For example,
$$
f(t)
=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}
t^2,&t<0\\
0,&0\leq t\leq 1\\
-\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}
(t-1)^2,&t>1
\end{cases}
$$
is a solution.

Your definition of $H_0$ requires that $f(0)=0$, as $f=0\iff h=H_0$.
With your update I think you mean $h(0)=0$ instead of $h(0)=H_0$.

Let us then see what happens with your added assumption that $h(t)\leq H_0$, $h$ is strictly increasing and $\lim_{t\to\infty}h(t)=H_0$.
With my notation this gives $f(t)\leq0$, $f'(t)\geq0$, and $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$.
The updated initial condition seems to be $f(0)=-H_0$.
Let's start with
$$
f(t)
=
-\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}
(t-t_0)^2.
$$
Putting in the initial condition gives
$$
-H_0
=
f(0)
=
-\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}
t_0^2,
$$
so
$$
f(t)
=
-a
(t-\sqrt{H_0/a})^2,
$$
where $a=\frac{8g}{r^2 - 1}$.
As $f$ should be increasing, we have
$$
f(t)
=
\begin{cases}
-a
(t-\sqrt{H_0/a})^2
,&
0\leq t\leq \sqrt{H_0/a}\\
0
,&
t>\sqrt{H_0/a}.
\end{cases}
$$
The function is increasing but not strictly increasing; it reaches it's final value in finite time.
Without the increasing assumption the solution can decide to "bounce back down" starting at any time after $t_0=\sqrt{H_0/a}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, the problem requires f(0) to be H_0 not zero. Additionally, the problem only needs to be defined for t>0. And I am assuming that for t --> inf h(t)=H_0 and thus f(t)=0. Perhaps this wold be enough to determine a solution?

Comment: @timlevert Notice that $h(t)=H_0\iff f(t)=0$. This change of functions I did at the start simplifies things. Is $r$ above of below one? Either way, it doesn't seem to be unique; the solution can stay still for any amount of time and then start moving as in my example. (If yo have any additional knowledge of your solution or coefficients, please include them in the question itself. It makes answering much easier.)

Comment: @Joonas_Illmavirta I have updated the post with some more information, hopefully it is helpfull.

Comment: @timlevert It is indeed, thanks! I updated the answer.

Comment: @Joonas_Illmavirta Thank you very much this really helps me a lot. I do however believe there is a mistake in the integral, as when I calculate it I get (sqrt(2)*sqrt(1-r^2)*sqrt(f))/sqrt(g).

Answer (score 2):

You could put it in the form 
$$\left(y’\right)^2 = ky $$
where $y =h-H_0$ and $k=-\lambda/\mu$.

With assumptions about various signs, you might even go for

$$y’=cy^{1/2}$$